# how to show the aspx site in the Iframe

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, iframe

I have a Button1 on the firstpage.aspx page and by Button1click I call a webservice in the codebehind which passes me a random number.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim test As localhost.servicetest = New localhost.servicetest

    Dim answer as string =test.randomnumber().tostring
End Sub
```

I have another aspx form secondpage.aspx which only consists of label, which I want to pass the answer variable from the webservice.

I added javascript to the firstpage.aspx which creates an iframe with secondpage.aspx

```js
(function () {
    $('#Button1').click(function () {
        $('<iframe />', {
            name: 'frame',
            id: 'frame',
            src:'secondpage.aspx'
        }).appendTo('body');
    });
    return false;
});
```

My first problem is that this way I dont know how to load the variable into the secondpage.aspx before I display them in the iframe.

Who do I do it? Do I really need to take the java code way or can I do all the things in the code behind?

My goal is to create an iframe with a "new instance" of secondpage.aspx with a new random number at every Buttonclick.

I hope you guys can help

Cheers Steven

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Session variable (Session[name]) and define a variable on your secondpage to store this value.

On the first page : "Dim answer as string =test.randomnumber().tostring"
You have to store answer in the Session and call it in the secondPage

Comment: or you can just call your webservice in the secondpage.aspx load method.